# Using LevelGraph with MemDOWN

Tags: javascript, node.js, leveldb

I've been trying to use [LevelGraph](https://github.com/mcollina/levelgraph) with [MemDOWN](https://github.com/rvagg/memdown), but my `put` and `get` queries are getting 100 times slower compared with using the filesystem directly with [LevelUP](https://github.com/rvagg/node-levelup). Obviously, I must be doing something wrong. I setup my graph database in the following fashion:

```
var levelgraph = require('levelgraph');
var db = levelgraph('mydb', { db: require('memdown')});
```

The following works just fine, but is using the filesystem:

```
var levelgraph = require('levelgraph');
var db = levelgraph('mydb');
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that MemDOWN is really simple (144 lines of [code](https://github.com/rvagg/memdown/blob/master/memdown.js)), and does not have any of the optimizations offered by other implementations of LevelDOWN. Kudos to [mcollina](https://github.com/mcollina) for the [answer](https://github.com/mcollina/levelgraph/issues/90). It is possible that [level-cache](https://github.com/Raynos/level-cache) could provide a faster implemtation (investigating).